# How do i retrive the city name from opengatedata.com

Tags: react-native, api, promise, geolocation, tsx

```
'''if (await permission()) {
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    async position => {
      await fetch(
        `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${position.coords.latitude}+${position.coords.longitude}&key=apikey&pretty=1`,
      ).then(result => {
        console.log(result.data);
      });
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error.code, error.message);
    },
  );
}'''
```

How do i retrive the returned location from the response sent to me
The things it sends me seems like gibrish and have no clue what to do and i am building the app in react-native using tsx

Comment: Can you paste a response from api or important part of it?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is console the response to make sure that you are receiving your response as expected after that you've multiple choices to extract the required data e.g. Destructuring or looping through the response (quite expensive + time taking) or you can use the filter method, in a nutshell, there are tons of way to get your required data from the response and it's just a matter of your taste(like whichever you prefer)